# Cabin Air Filter door on a 2011 Corolla

Tags: toyota, corolla, cabin-filter

I bought a 2011 Corolla and found out the cabin filter door is missing.  Would not having it on cause very little air to come out of the floor, dash and defrost outlets?

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question.

Comment: I'm sorry, it is the same basic question asking pretty much the same thing ... just stating it differently. If you'd like to appeal by clicking on the "Reopen" link at the bottom of the question, by all means. You can see if the other members of the site agree with you.